# Create slide menu using SWReavealController with TabbarViewController programmatically - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I am creating a sample app which contains `TabBarViewController` and also i implement slide menu using `SWRevealViewController` and the problem is that the slide menu it not showing out.

Here i set `rootViewController` in `appdelegate`

```
 window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

 window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

 window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()
```

Here is my `TabBarController` which i implement 2 tabBar items which first tabBar item should have slide menu

```
    let homeController = HomeController()
    let homeNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
    homeNavigation.tabBarItem.title = "Home"
    let menuController = MenuViewController()
    let swReveal = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: homeNavigation, frontViewController: menuController)
    swReveal?.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.easeOut
    swReveal?.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30

    let favController = FavoriteController()
    let favNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: favController)
    favNavigation.tabBarItem.title = "Favorite"
    viewControllers = [homeNavigation, favNavigation]
```

For `MenuController` i setup some navigation button for showing menu

```
    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(slideMenu))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
@objc func slideMenu() {

    if revealViewController() != nil {
        revealViewController().revealToggle(animated: true)
        revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = (view.bounds.width * 80 ) / 100
    }
    else {
        print("no reveal view")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share demo project?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni here sir 
 https://github.com/SamboVisal/TabbarWithSlideMenu

Comment: From your project implementation is not done correctly. You need to follow this tutorial. https://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: Oh. In this tutorial is explained by using storyboard which is very useful. But could you mention my mistakes on the demo project which i shared with you?

Comment: Ok posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure `SWRevealViewController` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as shown below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let frontNavigationController:UINavigationController
    let rearNavigationController:UINavigationController
    let revealController = SWRevealViewController()
    var mainRevealController = SWRevealViewController()

    frontNavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: TabBarController())
    rearNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MenuViewController())

    frontNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    rearNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    revealController.frontViewController = frontNavigationController
    revealController.rearViewController = rearNavigationController
    revealController.delegate = self
    mainRevealController  = revealController

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = mainRevealController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

And in your `HomeController` replace

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(slideMenu))
```

with

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(slideMenu))
```

And remove

```
let menuController = MenuViewController()
let swReveal = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: homeNavigation, frontViewController: menuController)
swReveal?.toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationType.easeOut
swReveal?.toggleAnimationDuration = 0.30
```

From your `TabBarController` and your final code will be:

```
func customTabbar (){

    let homeController = HomeController()
    let homeNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
    homeNavigation.tabBarItem.title = "Home"

    let favController = FavoriteController()
    let favNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: favController)
    favNavigation.tabBarItem.title = "Favorite"

    let servicePhoneCollectionFLowLayoutInstance = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let serviceTabbarFlowLayoutInit = ExploreController(collectionViewLayout: servicePhoneCollectionFLowLayoutInstance)

    let exploreController = serviceTabbarFlowLayoutInit
    let exploreNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: exploreController)
    exploreNavigation.tabBarItem.title = "Explore"


    let moreController = DetailViewController()
    let moreViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: moreController)
    moreViewController.tabBarItem.title = "Tools"
    viewControllers = [homeNavigation, favNavigation, exploreNavigation, moreViewController]
}
```

And for more info check your updated project [HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=99080854776263346806).

**Here is Working Code of** `SWRevealViewController` **with** `UINavigationController` **and** `UITabBarController` **by Storyboard (Swift 4)**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725803/10150796

Comment: I do appreciate for your wonderful time. Now i have some idea about making slide menu programmatically. Thank you so much...

Comment: Writing this after long time. :D Happy to help you. :)