# how to gradient a background of a tableview in swift

Tags: swift3

```
func setTableViewBackgroundGradient(sender: UITableViewController, _ topColor:UIColor, _ bottomColor:UIColor) {

    let gradientBackgroundColors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    let gradientLocations = [0.0,1.0]

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = gradientBackgroundColors
    gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]

    gradientLayer.frame = sender.tableView.bounds
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: sender.tableView.bounds)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    sender.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Please read [ask] and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this it's working for me (Swift 4)**

> Note : First of all set Tableview Cell & Cell ContentView Background
>   Color to Clear Color.

```
@IBOutlet fileprivate weak var tblVw: UITableView!

private var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if gradientLayer.superlayer != nil {
        gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }
    let topColor = UIColor(red: 16.0/255.0, green: 12.0/255.0, blue: 54.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 57.0/255.0, green: 33.0/255.0, blue: 61.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.frame = tblVw.bounds
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: tblVw.bounds)
    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    tblVw.backgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: sir it doesn't work it hides all content of table view

Comment: @abhishekrajput you missed someone in integration because it's working file please check it one again.

Comment: Dear Sir, i check it again. color hides the content of tableview . sir can you send me a project build so i can check it.  email:  rajput.abhishek660@gmail.com

Comment: @abhishekrajput You needs to set light dark color combination for component and background color. See the updated answer.

Comment: @abhishekrajput Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. If you've tried something, please update your question to show what you've tried and what the problem is.

Comment: Actually sir. cell label color is set to black  that's why it was not visible. thanks again sir. @NikunjKumbhani

Comment: @AshleyMills actually sir  i am a fresher that's why i did this. from next time i'll keep this thing on mind thankyou sir

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani sir i want to ask one thing . Can you help me ??

Comment: @abhishekrajput Yes say

Comment: sir actually i used https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift but when i used slide menu. the contains of mainscreen is showing to another screen

Comment: @abhishekrajput Use this one it's working fine by just using two classes no need to add framework and pod install. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725803/10150796

Comment: actually sir in this. Screen is shifted to right and i have to implement that type of slide menu (Slide Menu In). so sir help me in this

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani sir https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12maQmHJTju2-gHwd8BPIQGlwc35l42r7?usp=sharing

Comment: @abhishekrajput Check properly you missed something in integration.

Comment: Dear, it's not possible that I write code for you, You need to check it from your end.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani sir  i have tried many times. but i have same problem again and again

Comment: sir actually i shared a google drive link can you check it sir. i don't want you to write. but sir please find out the issues.

Comment: @abhishekrajput Not able to found storyboard in your folder some files are missing and it's not possible you can download the demo from GitHub and integrate carefully according to that you got the result.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani . https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z-TKpaYqJuG-3aPXnQUtD3YPXUABq0XF

Comment: @abhishekrajput Right now I just change **let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: rightViewController, rightMenuViewController: leftViewController)** in Appdelegate file of Github demo project and chek it's workig completely that means you missed something in integration so Create new project and do all things step by step same as demo project.

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani sir still facing same problem in this project

Comment: @abhishekrajput I say that change it in demo project's app delegate file, not in your project.