# Tabbar not showing when i open from side menu

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrintMainViewController")
            self.navigationController!.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

and also added:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: explain in detail so that we can help you.

Comment: want to show tababar when user clicks from sidemenu but it is not showing.but when it is from homecontroller it will showing.

Comment: Are you sure that `PrintMainViewController` is a subclass of a tab bar controller? The line `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false` will most likely do absolutely nothing in your code as `self.tabBarController` is `nil` if this is the same view controller as with the first snippet. If anything try `(controller as! UITabBarController).tabBar.isHidden = false`. If it crashes then this controller is not a subclass of tab bar controller.

Comment: @Dhara You need to change the selection of **tabBarController** while clicking from a side menu instance of **pushViewController** if you want to show tab bar in all.

Comment: No PrintMainViewController is not a subclass. it comes from sidemenu

Comment: can u pls explain in brief?? @Nikunj Kumbhani

Comment: @Dhara What is the side menu are you use any third-party Library?

Comment: yes swrevealviewcontroller i m using.

Comment: @Dhara **Great, I have already answered this question please check this** https://stackoverflow.com/a/51725803/10150796

Comment: thanks @NikunjKumbhani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your hierarchy correctly you have a tab bar controller which has navigation controllers in it. So basically any of the tabs can push additional view controllers and tab bar is still visible.

Now you want to push some new controller on the currently selected view controller in the tab bar and you want to do it from another part of the app, another view controller that has no relation to tab bar.

The quickest way to do that is to expose a static instance of your tab bar view controller. This will only work if you always have only 1 tab bar controller in your application (probably 99% of the applications).

First add a current instance to your tab bar view controller:

```
class MyTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    static private(set) var currentInstance: MyTabBarViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        MyTabBarViewController.currentInstance = self
    }

}
```

So when view loads a static value is assigned and can now be accessed anywhere in your project via `MyTabBarViewController.currentInstance`.

The rest is then just accessing the currently selected view controller and pushing a new view controller. Something like this should do:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrintMainViewController")
(MyTabBarViewController.currentInstance?.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController)?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank u @Matic Oblak

Comment: Its not working for me... Here's my code in side menu.

             TabbarController *tabClassObj = [TabbarController sharedInstance];
             [tabClassObj.selectedViewController pushViewController:vcIdentifier animated:YES];

Comment: @Sivagami does it crash or nothing happens? Try to give as much info as possible to “not working”. Put a breakpoint to the second line of code you posted. Then in console in your Xcode (usually found on bottom right) enter “po tabClassObj” and “po tabClassObj.selectedViewController” and let me know what the console prints back for both.

Comment: It's not pushing to next view controller.  I check in log, tabClassObj.selectedViewController has value(Navigation controller)
Please check this link, this is what am trying to achieve. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278538/show-tabbar-from-refrostedviewcontroller-sidemenu-objective-c

Comment: If `tabClassObj.selectedViewController` is indeed a navigation controller then this is a strange issue. Your calls should be correct and this part of the code should be working correctly. Other candidates would be (not limited to) that you are calling this code on non-main thread, that this navigation controller is not on top at that time (some other controller is presented over it or other tab bar is shown), that the controller is instantly popped, that `controller` is null...

Answer (score -1):

You must push in TabBarController

```
self.tabBarController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```